# How to speed up a slow left join SQL query using the with statement?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

I have a left join query (in Snowflake) that is on multiple columns. `X` has 11 million rows and `Y` has 100 million rows. It is very slow (around 25 minutes) and needs to be run many times per day. Is there anyway to speed it up maybe using the with statement (or any other approaches)? Here is the query:

```
select id, start_ts, start_ts_lgn from
(select id, start_ts 
    from X
    where start_ts >= '2019-11-01')a
left join
(select id as id_frm_lgn, cast(cast(strt_dt as varchar(10))||' '||cast(strt_tm as varchar(12)) as timestamp) as start_ts_lgn
    from Y
    where strt_dt >= '2019-10-01')b
on a.id = b.id_frm_lgn
and a.start_ts > b.start_ts_lgn;
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid SQL. You have a `join` without a `from` clause.

Comment: is it slow even after indexing?

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--including cut & paste & runnable minimal code & minimal representative data given as code. For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL, including constraints, indexes & tabular initialization. For SQL performance that includes EXPLAIN results & statistics. Please research & summarize. For SQL that includes basics of optimization/performance--immediately leading to indexes, plans, statistics & SARGability. [Tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/271056/3404097) Ask re optimization after you have learned & applied those basics. [ask]

Comment: @GMB Sorry the first line was missing.

Comment: @philipxy I edited the question.

Comment: I don't know why you notified me. Your edit is clearly not acting on all of my comment.

Comment: Isn't the section `date >= '2019-10-01'` equivalent to `strt_dt >= '2019-10-01'`? If you can rephrase it that way the performance can be improved quite a bit.

Comment: @TheImpaler Fixed that, thanks!

Comment: @shawnt00 B needs to be earlier than A, since `a.start_ts > b.start_ts_lgn`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To speed this query you can add the indexes:

```
create index ix1 on X (start_ts, id);

create index ix2 on Y (strt_dt, id);
```

Comment: Does this affect the main tables (I don't own them)?

Comment: You need to have privileges on the database table to create indexes. Anyway, it differs depending on the specific engine (you don't mention which one). Also the side effects of an index are usually marginal (unless you create tons of them).

Comment: How can I index `Y` if the `date` column doesn't actually exist? In the actual query it is `cast(cast(strt_dt as varchar(10))||' '||cast(strt_tm as varchar(12))  as timestamp) as date`. I simplified it in the question.

Comment: Ah... that has *huge* implications in performance. Your query suffers from "expression on the left side of the comparison". Please update your question, since this affects the whole analysis.

Comment: Done! Sorry, I was trying to make it simpler.

Comment: @Fred I modified the second index, according to the updated question.

Comment: I am using Snowflake and it doesn't support indexing, apparently. However I still marked this as the answer, because it was my fault that didn't mention Snowflake. Thanks anyways.